# AngularJS: Get all file names in the src/app/templates directory

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I would like to get all the template file names for my webpage, they are all located within src/app/templates.

For one of my scripts I am using $templateCache to run a job on each file inside that directory, but I have to manually list all the file names when calling $templateCache.get('filename')

I need a way to automatically get this list but $templateCache does not have a getAll() function.

Comment: Create a PHP (or whatever) script that list the content of your src/app/templates directory and call that script from your AngularJS app, if doing the job on client side is what you want...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a task runner like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) with [gulp-angular-templatecache](https://github.com/miickel/gulp-angular-templatecache)